# AutoHotKey dumb syntax issue (Two functions in the same script)

Tags: autohotkey

I have two functions below. They work by themselves but i can't get them to work in the same script. The one at the bottom won't work. Can someone help me to fix. For example, below "LShift & RShift" or "RShift & LShift" won't work. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
endKeys := "{BS}{Enter}{Insert}{Home}{Pgup}{PdDwn}End}{Delete}" 
     . "{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}"
     . "{LShift}{RShift}{Tab}{Esc}{CAPSLOCK}{Ctrl}{PrintScreen}{NumLock}" 
     . "{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}" 
     . "{Numpad7}{Numpad8}{Numpad9}{NumpadDel}{Up}{Down}{Left}{Right}"
     . "{LAlt}{RAlt}{.}{,}{/}"

~Alt Up::
    Input, key, V L1 t0.5 E, % endKeys
    If (Errorlevel ~= "Alt") {
        Double_ALT := true
        Sleep 2000
        Double_ALT := false
    }
return

; Press a key within two seconds after double tapping the Alt key, to activate an action:
#If (Double_ALT)
    a:: MsgBox, Test
    b:: MsgBox, Test
    c:: MsgBox, Test
    d::
    FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,,MM/dd/yy - hh:mmtt
    SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
            Double_ALT :=false
            return
    s:: MsgBox, Test
    f:: MsgBox, Test
return

LShift & RShift::
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,,MM/dd/yy - hh:mmtt
SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
return

RShift & LShift::
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,,MM/dd/yy - hh:mmtt
SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
endKeys := "{BS}{Enter}{Insert}{Home}{Pgup}{PdDwn}End}{Delete}" 
     . "{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}"
     . "{LShift}{RShift}{Tab}{Esc}{CAPSLOCK}{Ctrl}{PrintScreen}{NumLock}" 
     . "{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}" 
     . "{Numpad7}{Numpad8}{Numpad9}{NumpadDel}{Up}{Down}{Left}{Right}"
     . "{LAlt}{RAlt}{.}{,}{/}"

~Alt Up::
    Input, key, V L1 t0.5 E, % endKeys
    If (Errorlevel ~= "Alt") {
        Double_ALT := true
        Sleep 2000
        Double_ALT := false
    }
return

; Press a key within two seconds after double tapping the Alt key, to activate an action:
#If (Double_ALT)
    a:: MsgBox, Test
    b:: MsgBox, Test
    c:: MsgBox, Test
    d::
    FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,,MM/dd/yy - hh:mmtt
    SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
            Double_ALT :=false
            return
    s:: MsgBox, Test
    f:: MsgBox, Test
; return <-- likely your problem.

; #IF <-- Use this if you don't want your hotkeys below effected by the IF Directive

LShift & RShift::
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,,MM/dd/yy - hh:mmtt
SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
return

RShift & LShift::
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,,MM/dd/yy - hh:mmtt
SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
return
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. One other question. The LShift & RShift seems to have a minor bug. Sometimes, I think when you press a Shift a 3rd time quickly, it somehow registers the Shift as held down until you press one of the Shifts a number of times again to release it. When it's in that state anything you select with the mouse gets highlighted. Is this not the most elegant way to do this or do you see what could be causing it and a fix?